# Invoke a method on all subclasses from superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I have recently stubled upon something that has always annoyed me.

Whenever I want a method to be invoked in all classes that have a certain interface, or if they are extensions, I would like to have a keyword that does the opposite of the keyword *super*. Basically, I want the invocation to be passed down **(if a class inherits a method, and the method in the superclass is called, it will be called in the subclass as well)**. Is there anything that resembles what I am asking for?

**EDIT:
The contemporary methods I am using are efficient, but not as efficient as I would like them to be. I am only wondering if there is a way of invoking a method, that has been inherited, from its superclass/superinterface. The last time I was looking for this, I did not find it either.**

**NOTE: All of the subclasses are unknown, hence impossible to utilize. The only known class is the superclass, which is why I can't invoke it. This can be solved using the Reflections API, which I am currently using. However, it does not always comply with what I am searching for.**

Comment: It's not clear to me. Can you explain a bit more with some sample. How a super class knows about its subclasses?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: OMG! Please, let us know what do you need it for!

Comment: By "unknown" do you mean that you haven't instantiated them??

Answer (score 3):

Every method in Java is `virtual` with the exception of `static` methods, `final` methods and constructors meaning that if a subclass implements the method being invoked, the subclass's implementation will be called.  If the subclass wishes to also invoke the immediate superclass method, that is accomplished via a call to `super`.

This is very common with abstract classes where some base class is utilized by a framework, but clients are expected to override.  For instance:

```
public abstract class Drawer{
  public void draw(){
     //setup code, etc common to all subclass implementations
     doDraw();
  }
  protected abstract void doDraw();
}

public class CircleDrawer extends Drawer{
  protected void doDraw(){
    //implementation of how to actually draw a circle
  }
}
```

Now, when you have an instance of `CircleDrawer` and you call `draw()`, the superclass `Drawer.draw()` method will be invoked that is, in turn, able to call `CicleDrawer.doDraw()`.

**Edit** Now, if `CircleDrawer` was this:

```
public class CircleDrawer extends Drawer{
  public void draw(){
    //do stuff
  }
  protected void doDraw(){
    //implementation of how to actually draw a circle
  }
}
```

Any invocation of `Drawer.draw()` on an instance of `CircleDrawer` will *always* invoke the `CircleDrawer.draw()` method.

Comment: I know that my question is vague, since what I am asking for, might not exist. What I am looking for, would invoke *draw()* in the *Drawer* class, which in turn, would invoke the same method in the *CircleDrawer* class (and in all other classes that extend *Drawer*).

Comment: That was exactly what I did before I came here, looking for answers.

Comment: @Seal, don't know what to tell you, that's how it works.  I've done it more times than I can count.  Are you sure that you were operating on an instance of the subclass and not actually an instance of the super class?  If you have instantiated the `Drawer` object (assuming it's not abstract) then there's no way it could possibly call the subclass's implementation because it doesn't know about it!

Comment: @Seal so are you saying if you instantiate a CircleDrawer, and you call the draw() method on that CircleDrawer, that it will first call draw() in Drawer, then run the code for draw() in CircleDrawer?

Lets assume "sub" is the opposite of "super":

You want something like `class Circle { public void draw() { stuff(); sub.draw(); } }`?

Comment: Yes, @ZachM. However, it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @ChrisThompson, I have been working with this for quite some time. However, I have never had any reason to use something like this. Now that I am in need of it, I am simply trying to find if there is a more efficient alternative.

Comment: @Seal Chris's solution using `draw()` and `doDraw()` is definitely the way to go about this.  If you make `draw()` final, and `doDraw()` either abstract or just not final, then you can ensure that when `draw()` is called on any implementation of Drawer, the code in the super class will be called (since no one can override `draw()`) and either the default implementation of `doDraw()` in Drawer (if `doDraw()` is not abstract) or the overridden implementation  in any subclass will get called.  With this pattern, you also get to choose if your code runs before `doDraw()`, after, or conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like this:

```
class A {
    public void func1(){
         //do stuff
         subclass.func1();
    }
}
class B extends A{
    public void func1(){
         //do more stuff
    }
}
class C extends A{
}
```

What happens when I call `new C().func1()`?  Remember, `func1` is not abstract and therefore, you cannot require classes to define it.

A better solution is to do the following:

```
abstract class A {
    public void func1(){
         //do stuff
         func2();
    }
    public abstract func2();
}
class B extends A{
    public void func2(){
         //do more stuff
    }
}
```

Hence, you require your subclasses to define a function that you can call from the super class.

Answer (score 1):

The is no such a thing. When calling an overriden method in Java, the child-most class's method will be always called. If you want to call parent methods as well, you need to use `super.methodCall()` in every class's method of your hirearchy.

Comment: I guess I will have to stick with the old way of doing it, if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe the thing you are trying to do is as possible as you may think. It's not quite that easy to invoke your subclasses from the super class, because not all subclasses may behave in the same way so a generic keyword for that functionality would wreak havoc! Although, by the phrasing of "Basically, I want the invocation to be passed down." it sounds like what you want is normal inheritance.

Just define the most generic similarities that all subclasses have in common in the superclass, then simply start each subclass definition of the method with `super()`

I don't mean to point out the obvious, but OO was designed for that and not for what you are asking. I doubt you'll be unable to find a way to do what you want within the typical arsenal of OO concepts

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused describing what you need, I don't think this:

> Whenever I want a method to be invoked in all classes that have a certain interface, or if they are extensions

Is the same as this:

> I would like to have a keyword that does the opposite of the keyword super

From what I understand, in the first one, you are referring to calling a method for all instances of a base class and its subclasses. For the second one, calling a subclass' method is exactly calling that method on a subclass which has probably overriden it.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, maybe you should clarify with an example. Most likely, yours is a design problem which is solved in a different way than the one you are proposing. However, a "solution" came to mind when reading your question.

I'm a little more experienced with C# and python than with Java (and not even that much), but I'm sure more experienced programmers won't hesitate to correct me if I said stupid things.

You should have some kind of collection of objects of type of the base class and call that method, on each object, which each subclass must have overriden.

Maybe using the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which is commonly used to reproduce event triggering, you can make all instances of a base class and its subclasses execute a "callback" whenever you want.

Comment: The opposite of "super.invokeSomeMethod();", that invokes the method in its superclass; would be "sub.invokeSomeMethod();", that invokes the method in its subclasses. However, the keyword 'sub' does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's what you were asking for, the thing is a method does not get invoked from a class or a subclass, but from an instance, which belongs to a class or a subclass...the lowest class hierarchy an instance belongs to (and whose methods it can access) would actually be the instance's class... basically I was trying to explain why "sub" doesn't exist... it's not possible, nor logical...